# Emulating hard keyboard lid

Tags: android, keyboard

The configuration options of Android emualtor include parameter: `hw.keyboard.lid,` which presumably allows to emulate hiding hard keybard (which triggers onConfigurationChange with HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES). However I cannot figure out the way to do that. Android [list of keyboard commands for emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) does not mention keyboard lid, some other relevant theads in this forum don't provide a helpful answer either. Any new ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? Simulate hide of the hard keyboard (on a device , on emulator?) ?

Comment: Yes, I as said before, I need to test hiding a keyboard.

Comment: I posted an Answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to enable the hardware keyboard on your Android Emulator, it depends on the operating system you're using and on the version of the SDK version.

As said [here](https://coderwall.com/p/i2heaw):

For Windows ->
Go in the folder of the AVD, open the `config.ini` file there and put `hw.keyboard=yes` (folder: `~/.android/avd/<emulator-device-name>.avd/config.ini`).

For Mac OS and Linux, use this command ->

```
for f in ~/.android/avd/*.avd/config.ini; do echo 'hw.keyboard=yes' >> "$f"; done
```

Then, if you're using SDK rev 21 (as said here), on the "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)", there's an option with "Hardware keyboard Present" and a checkbox.

This whole thing is also explained [here](http://android-trek.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-enable-keyboard-support-in.html):

> **Procedure 1**: Enable keyboard property from installed folder structure
>
> - Go to ".android" directory
> - Open "avd" directory where list of emulator instances folders can be seen (if multiple instances created)
> - Open the specific emulator folder for which we are targeting to enable the keyboard
> - edit the "hardware-qemu.ini" file
> - change hardware keyboard property to "Yes"
>                "hw.keyboard = yes"
>
> In my case folder structure is as below
>   C:\Users\i047495.android\avd\raj_avd.avd File name
>   "hardware-qemu.ini"

[image]

> **Procedure 2**: Enable keyboard property from Eclipse
>
> Eclipse > Window menu > AVD Manager Select your virtual device and
>   click Edit Under Hardware, Click New Select Keyboard Support then
>   click OK Edit its value to yes

[image]

That's about all that can be said on this topic.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but the question was not how to configure emulator, but how to emulate lid open/closed using emulator.